# How do I figure out the correct DRIVER string for ODBC SQL connection (in python)

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc

I have a python script that is using sqlAlchemy to connect to a SQL Server DB. We moved the DB from  a local server in the closet to AWS.

When running from a mac, I have:

```
            'DRIVER=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so',
```

and that works for both closet and AWS

on a Windows machine, for the closet the connection contained:

```
 'DRIVER=SQL Server',
```

which gives the error message:

```
(pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Cannot generate SSPI context (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Cannot generate SSPI context (0)')
```

searching around, tells me that maybe I need a new driver, so:
https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows recommends:

```
        'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}}'
```

(Because I'm formatting into the connection string, so I need to escape the {})

gives:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM012', '[IM012] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] DRIVER keyword syntax error (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

alternatively,

```
        'DRIVER=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server',
```

gives:

```
(pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

This SQLAlchemy engine works:

```
Engine(mssql+pyodbc://cam-tls1:1433/services_vars?driver=SQL Server)
```

This one does not:

```
Engine(mssql+pyodbc://P-CEP-SQL:1433/services_vars?driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server})
```

it gives a syntax error on the DRIVER keyword...

Do I need to download a new library? or do I need to specify the driver differently?

Comment: Start by reading the pyodbc documentation on their home site, or the pyodbc documentation written by Microsoft and the community on docs.microsoft.com (which is transitioning to learn.microsoft.com). Also driver names are often wrapped in `{` and `}` characters.

Comment: I tried with and without the {} The formatting makes it hard to read. I'll fix that.

Comment: and the page I link **IS** the Pyodbc documentation, which is what docs.microsoft.com links to...

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not exactly sure how I was SUPPOSED To find this out, but this works:

```
        'DRIVER=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server',
```

even though 18 appears to be current, it doesn't work for 18. but it does work for 17.