# how do I fix this pyodbc Driver syntax error

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, sqlalchemy, odbc

I'm using SQLAlchemy in python on a windows machine to connect to a SQL Server. I'm pretty sure that I am generating the SQL engine correctly, I have:

```
Engine(mssql+pyodbc://P-CEP-SQL:1433/services_vars?driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server})
```

A previous version, connecting to a different copy of the same server works with:

```
Engine(mssql+pyodbc://cam-tls1:1433/services_vars?driver=SQL Server)
```

however, with the Driver 18 line, I'm now getting:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM012', '[IM012] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] DRIVER keyword syntax error (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

when I remove the {} I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Which I'm pretty sure means that it can't find the driver....

It gives this for any string with { } in it, but I'm pretty sure that that's the correct name of the driver. Do I need to extra escape something?

Comment: This is a reframing of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74061402/how-do-i-figure-out-the-correct-driver-string-for-odbc-sql-connection-in-python Feel free to suggest I close whichever version is worse.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax appears to be:
'DRIVER=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server',

This works for version 17, but not 18 for some reason.

Comment: It could be that your local ODBC driver registered under the name with 17 in it. On Windows you look the registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\Odbcinst.ini`. On UNIX you look to `odbcinst -j`, usially it points to `/etc/odbcinst.ini`